# Prevent shiny app from breaking a while loop

Tags: r, while-loop, shiny

I am trying to run a shiny app within a while loop. Upon exiting the app, the while loop breaks. Is there a way to stay within the loop upon exiting the app?

Here is an example of the problem. The app.R file is the app created upon creating a new shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

x <- 1

while(x<=5){

  runApp("app.R")

  x <- x+1

}
```

Comment: Is `runApp("app.R")` producing an error? If so, you need to catch the error, perhaps with `try` or `tryCatch`.

Comment: No error, it just exits the while loop. I have tried ```tryCatch()``` and ```suppressMessages()``` and it still breaks the loop.

Comment: (`suppressMessages` only prevents messages from being dumped to the console, it does nothing to program flow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" way to stop a Shiny application is to simply stop the R process that's serving it. You need a way to close the app without breaking. The `stopApp()` function does that, returning control of the thread back to the main flow of your script.

This example is from the help page at `?runApp`, and I've made two additions commented below.

```
library(shiny)

x <- 1
while (x <= 5) {
  runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
      numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
      plotOutput('plot'),
      actionButton("done", "close")         # added a close button
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
      observeEvent(input$done, stopApp())   # added an observer to the close button
    }
  ))
  x <- x+1
}
```

You can also put an argument from the logic of the Shiny app inside `stopApp()`, so that you can use the result in your other calculations. For this example, if we wanted to know what the user input for `n`, we could use `stopApp(input$n)`, and the whole app would return that value, like below.

```
x <- 1
while (x <= 5) {
  user_input <- runApp(<code from above>)
  x <- x+1
}
```

The important thing is to make it obvious to your users that they need to use your "close" button within the app, instead of closing the browser window or using the "Stop" button in RStudio. Either of those actions will interrupt your main script.

---

### Edited to add:

There are actually some functions builtin to `{shiny}` to listen for a user's session ending (i.e. closing the browser window), `onStop()` and `onSessionEnded()`. You should check out the help page for them, but replacing my `observeEvent(...)` line with `onStop(stopApp)` (or `onSessionEnded(stopApp)`) seems to work just fine. Then you can remove the Close button from the UI.